# Lookup Filtering on D365 x++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I am a beginner at d365 finance and operations. I have service and sub-service lookup fields in a form. This field's data sources have a one-to-many relationship with a foreign key. When I select a record in the service field, I want to see only sub-services that belong to the selected 'service' record in the 'sub-services lookup field. I need a lookup filtering for this with X++ but I do not know-how.
I would be really appreciated it if someone can help me with this.

Here is my code but I really confused all the tables and fields name and I probably write the wrong names in the wrong places.

//My main form that includes lookup fields is inventSite
// Control names of lookup fields are InvenSite_ServiceRefRecId and InventSite_SubServiceRefRecId
//The name of the form that includes service and subservice records is Service
// the table that includes subservice records is SubService

Here is my Service form
[image: Service form]

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(InventSite, InventSite_SubServiceRefRecId), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
   public static void InventSite_SubServiceRefRecId_OnLookup(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
   {
       SysReferenceTableLookup sysRefTableLookup;
       Query query = new Query();
       QueryBuildDataSource qbds;

       FormRun formRun;
       FormControl formCtrl;
       ServiceName serviceName;
       FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs ce = e as FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs;

       sysRefTableLookup = SysReferenceTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(Service), sender);
       qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(Service));
       formRun = sender.formRun();

        
       formCtrl = formRun.design().controlName(formControlStr(InventSite, InventSite_SubServiceRefRecId));
       serviceName = formCtrl.valueStr();

       qbds.firstOnly(true);
       qbds.addRange(fieldNum(Service, ServiceName)).value(queryValue(serviceName));

       sysRefTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
       sysRefTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Service, ServiceName));
       sysRefTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Service, ServiceDescription));
        
       sysRefTableLookup.performFormLookup();

       ce.CancelSuperCall();
   }
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add an overview of the data structures you are working with?

Comment: I edited and added my code can you please help me?

Comment: How do you determine what subservices are allowed for a selected service? Does the subservice table have a relation to the service table?

Comment: Yes, I added a foreign key relation to subservice table with recid of service table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overide lookup. Please find an example here in community blog. https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/365foandaxtechnicalworld/posts/override-lookup-ax7-amp-d365fo

Comment: My code is similar to this actually, I added my code but I got confused with the tables and fields and I am afraid I put them in the wrong places. Can you please help me?

Comment: You wanted to filter subservice. So you need to use SubService table in below code instead of Service table.

sysRefTableLookup = SysReferenceTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(Service), sender);
       qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(Service));

qbds.addRange(fieldNum(Service, ServiceName)).value(queryValue(serviceName));

       sysRefTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
       sysRefTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Service, ServiceName));
       sysRefTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Service, ServiceDescription));

Comment: Then to get form control value of Service field you should be using  InventSite_ServiceRefRecId  and not "SubServiceRefRecId".
formCtrl = formRun.design().controlName(formControlStr(InventSite, InventSite_SubServiceRefRecId));