# How can I say that few values are not meant to display in a lookup field of form in finance and operations d365 x++?

Tags: x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a field named ScaleID that has been created in the form level in Form1. This field has two methods associated with it. One is jumpref which is responsible for navigating to another form. Another method is edit, this is triggered when this is field switched to edit mode. Most importantly, this field has a lookup which gets value from another form named Form2. In the Form2, I have another field named status included to every record in that form, says that the particular record is active or not. My problem is if the record is active (status to yes) in the Form2, then only that particular record should be displayed in the lookup of the field ScaleID in Form1. If it is not active ( status to no ), then the record should not display in the lookup.

I am expecting the lookup should show only the active records (status to yes) on the lookup of the Form1.

Comment: Take a look if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642702/lookup-filtering-on-d365-x

Answer (score 0):

Use a range in a lookup method:

```
qbr = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(table, Field));
qbr.value(queryValue(NoYes::Yes));
```